# Single row result of join sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select

I have an sql query :

```
SELECT p.id, p.firstname, p.lastname, p.emailcollected, p.phone, e.accountid, e.accounttype
FROM player p
JOIN bankaccountinfo e ON p.id = e.playerid
WHERE ( ( p.createtime > 0 AND p.createtime < 2000000000 ) OR
        ( p.updatetime > 0 AND p.updatetime < 200000000000000 ) )
  AND e.accounttype IN ( 5002,5003 ) ;
```

This returns result in 2 rows are there are 2 enum type of account type :

```
+--------------+-----------+----------+----------------+------------+---------------+-------------+
| id           | firstname | lastname | emailcollected | phone      | accountnumber | accounttype |
+--------------+-----------+----------+----------------+------------+---------------+-------------+
|            9 | dineshND  | NineND   |     1536064455 | 5175761111 | 102323        |        5002 |
|            9 | dineshND  | NineND   |     1536064455 | 5175761111 | 102324        |        5003 |
+--------------+-----------+----------+----------------+------------+---------------+-------------+
```

But i want accountnumber to be displayed in single line as savingaccountnumber and checkingaccountnumber based on accounttype.

*Expected Result:*

```
+--------------+-----------+----------+----------------+------------+---------------------+-----------------------+
| id           | firstname | lastname | emailcollected | phone      | savingaccountnumber | checkingaccountnumber |
+--------------+-----------+----------+----------------+------------+---------------------+-----------------------+
|            9 | dineshND  | NineND   |     1536064455 | 5175761111 | 102323              |            102324     |
+--------------+-----------+----------+----------------+------------+---------------------+-----------------------+
```

- savingaccountnumber column when accounttype is 5003
- checkingaccountnumber column when accountype is 5002
- My Mysql version : **mysql  Ver 14.12 Distrib 5.0.51a, for debian-linux-gnu (i486) using readline 5.2**

Comment: Try with `Group By' playercardid

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: "Try with `Group By' playercardid" No very bad suggestion @Siva not `GROUP BY` it's not logical to "unduplicate" using `GROUP BY`  `DISTINCT` is meant to unduplicate.. Besides it tends to generate [invalid data](https://www.psce.com/en/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/) because MySQL extended GROUP BY "feature" when selecting columns which are not in the `GROUP BY` clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your sample data and expected result you can try to use condition aggravated function

```
SELECT id,
    firstname,
    lastname,
    emailcollected,
    phone,
    MAX(CASE WHEN accounttype = 5003 THEN accountid END) savingaccountnumber,
    MAX(CASE WHEN accounttype = 5002 THEN accountid END) checkingaccountnumber
FROM (
    SELECT p.id, p.firstname, p.lastname, p.emailcollected, p.phone, e.accountid, e.accounttype
    FROM player p
    JOIN bankaccountinfo e ON p.id = e.playerid
    WHERE ( ( p.createtime > 0 AND p.createtime < 2000000000 ) OR
            ( p.updatetime > 0 AND p.updatetime < 200000000000000 ) )
      AND e.accounttype IN ( 5002,5003 ) 
) t1 
GROUP BY  id,firstname,lastname,emailcollected,phone
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to join on `bankaccountinfo` twice to get things in one row: once for checking and once for savings. Assuming you (a) want to return a row even if the account records are missing, and (b) that there is a unique key defined on `bankaccountinfo` for `playerid, accounttype` :

```
SELECT
    p.id,
    p.firstname,
    p.lastname,
    p.emailcollected,
    p.phone,
    e1.accountid checkingaccountnumber,
    e2.accountid savingaccountnumber
FROM
    player p
LEFT JOIN
    bankaccountinfo e1
ON
    p.id = e1.playerid
    AND e1.accounttype = 5002
LEFT JOIN
    bankaccountinfo e2
ON
    p.id = e2.playerid
    AND e2.accounttype = 5003
WHERE
    (p.createtime > 0 AND p.createtime < 2000000000)
    OR (p.updatetime > 0 AND p.updatetime < 200000000000000)
```

Either way, brush up on what JOIN and IN do to understand why you got two results.